# Scrolling through array positively and negatively

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm creating a script where the the user would be presented 10 files and I would like to give the user the option to scroll to the next page using 1 and 2 on the keyboard as their input. I have written the following script however I can't achieve what I seem to happen. Any help in regards to this would be greatly appreciated!

Example:

```
1) Previous page
2) Next page
3) Contact Details
4) Main menu
```

Those would be the options that a user could use or enter when prompted. I have written a sample script however it doesn't give me the result that I would like probably because of a logical error and the index counter always go negative (I'm assuming it only passes through the first `if`)

```
declare -a manual=("$pg1" "$pg2" "$pg3" "$pg4" "$pg5" "$pg6" "$pg7" "$pg8" "$pg9" "$pg10")
x=0
while [ $x -lt "10" ]
do
read a
    if [ a -eq 1 ];
    then echo ${manual[$x-1]}
    x=$(($x-1))
    elif [ a -eq 2 ];
    then echo ${manual[$x+1]}   
    x=$(($x+1))
    elif [ a -eq 3 ];
    then echo ${manual[10]}
    else [ a -eq 4 ];
    bash mainmenu.sh
    fi
done
```

I'm fairly new to scripting to help and answers would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to replace `a` with `$a` in the if statements of your script:

e.g. :

```
if [ $a -eq 1 ];
```

you may also change the test at the beginning of the loop to check that the value of x is positive or null, so that `x` doesn't go out of range:

```
if [ $a -eq 1 -a $x -gt 0 ];
```

Comment: Seems like it was just a small mishap on my end! Thanks for the heads up!